CI/CD Pipeline using GitHub Actions: Automated PRs showing Historical Release Commits
This is our branch structure: issue_branch for feature/issues, dev, and main
Developers create an issue_branch from dev, make and test their changes, then create a Pull Request from issue_branch to dev which undergoes manual review before merging. When a PR is merged to dev, it triggers the create-main-pr job, which automatically creates a PR from dev to main.
Issue - when the PR is created in main, it is showing the commit history from the previous releases as well.
Expected result - when the PR is created in main, it should show only the new commits since the last release.  I know why it is showing the previous commit history (because of the SHA) but not sure how to fix this. This is happening even for one small change, which means there is only commit and not just for squash merges.  Here is my partial code:

create-main-pr:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 10
    if: |
      github.event_name == 'pull_request' &&
      github.event.action == 'closed' &&
      github.event.pull_request.merged == true &&
      github.event.pull_request.base.ref == 'dev'
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}

      - name: Create Pull Request
        id: create-pr
        uses: peter-evans/create-pull-request@v5
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.MY_SECRET }}
          commit-message: "chore: promote dev to main"
          branch: promote-dev-to-main
          delete-branch: true
          title: " Promote Dev to Main"
          body: |
            ## Automated Promotion PR
            
            This PR was automatically created to promote changes from `dev` to `main`.
            
            ### ✅ Pre-merge Checklist
            - [ ] Changes have been reviewed
            - [ ] Tests are passing
            - [ ] Documentation is up to date
            
            ###  Notes
            - This PR was automatically generated
            - Please review carefully before merging
            - Manual merge required
          labels: |
            automated
            promotion
          base: main
          branch-suffix: timestamp


Here is what I tried: I synced the main and dev right after a release, created an issue_branch, made a small change and created a PR and merged into dev.  This triggered the create-main-pr job which created a PR in main.  This PR is still showing all the commits from the previous release.

IIUC, it's related to the complete commit history. Did you try removing fetch-depth: 0 from the checkout step?

If I remove fetch-depth: 0, the default would be set to 1, which would fetch only the last commit.  This will not work for me

I resolved this by performing a hard reset on dev, syncing main and dev, and then using merge commits to main instead of squash merges.
